# Flask API to get data from another process with Queues

Tags: python, flask, python-multiprocessing

I have a code that make some analysis for me and save informations on an `multiprocessing.Queue`.

E.g.

```
import multiprocessing 
import time 

q = multiprocessing.Queue

for i in range(1000):
    q.put(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I want start an flask REST API that returns the value on `q`, but I'm not finding any way to do this.

I tried this, but doesn't nothing, just close.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import flask

class API():
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.p = Process(name='FlaskTest', target=self.start , args=())
    
    def start(self, host='0.0.0.0', port='5000', debug=True):

        app = flask.Flask(__name__)

        @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
        def home():
            return "<h1>Se isso der certo vou ficar muito feliz</h1>"

        app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = API()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the `start()` method on your `API` object so it's only creating the `API()` object and exiting.

Comment: God, I forgot. It Start but return : `\python.exe: No module named _name_of_the_file_` and close

Comment: Run with `app.run(use_reloader=False)` worked! Thanks